# KSOAP2 for Android generates sporadic error

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, ksoap2

I have a strange error with the code below: all is working fine for hours, but sometimes I have an exception and my app closes.

This is my piece of code that I call very frequently (every 15 seconds)

```
String URL = wscfg.server_address + "/xmds.php";
SoapObject localSoapObject = new SoapObject("", "registerDisplay");
localSoapObject.addProperty("serverKey", wscfg.server_key);
localSoapObject.addProperty("hardwareKey", wscfg.hardware_key);
localSoapObject.addProperty("version", wscfg.server_version);
localSoapObject.addProperty("displayName", wscfg.device_name);
SoapSerializationEnvelope localSoapSerializationEnvelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
localSoapSerializationEnvelope.bodyOut = localSoapObject;
new HttpTransportSE(URL).call("", localSoapSerializationEnvelope);
String s = (String)localSoapSerializationEnvelope.getResponse();
```

The exception is:

```
01-22 13:33:55.048: E/AndroidRuntime(567): FATAL EXCEPTION: Timer-5
01-22 13:33:55.048: E/AndroidRuntime(567): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-22 13:33:55.048: E/AndroidRuntime(567):  at org.ksoap2.transport.ServiceConnectionSE.getResponseProperties(ServiceConnectionSE.java:85)
01-22 13:33:55.048: E/AndroidRuntime(567):  at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:189)
01-22 13:33:55.048: E/AndroidRuntime(567):  at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:114)
01-22 13:33:55.048: E/AndroidRuntime(567):  at com.gmgunderground.test.xmds.WebServiceManager.requiredFiles(WebServiceManager.java:66)
01-22 13:33:55.048: E/AndroidRuntime(567):  at com.gmgunderground.test.xmds.XmdsService.TimerSchedulerSupervisor(XmdsService.java:267)
01-22 13:33:55.048: E/AndroidRuntime(567):  at com.gmgunderground.test.xmds.XmdsService.access$1(XmdsService.java:248)
01-22 13:33:55.048: E/AndroidRuntime(567):  at com.gmgunderground.test.xmds.XmdsService$3.run(XmdsService.java:552)
01-22 13:33:55.048: E/AndroidRuntime(567):  at java.util.Timer$TimerImpl.run(Timer.java:284)
```

How can I solve this error? Is there a way to prevent application from closing and return only null? As I can see from logcat the error is inside the KSOAP2 Android Library.

Best regards

Gian